# Where do you find the runlist (Vagrant)?

Tags: vagrant, apt

According to this link
[Chef Solo error: Cookbook apt not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15497610/chef-solo-error-cookbook-apt-not-found/15497746#15497746)

it says, i have to add apt cookbook in runlist.

I downloaded the apt-cookbook but I don't know where the runlist is.

Help.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you configuring this setup? If you are doing it on AWS Opswork then in that respective layer setup you can mention the runlist under its Recipe section.

One thing to note is that the sequence in runlist also matter, you should have to specify 'apt::default' first then other recipe.